# Why does my image not show up in the component

Tags: reactjs

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

The images show up fine locally but when I upload it to the server, it doesn't.

How can I update the path of the images so it works both locally and on my web server?

Does it make sense to set the slideData in a state since I might access it multiple functions within my component?

Comment: If you are using webpack, did u try `https://github.com/webpack-contrib/url-loader` ?

Comment: I used CRA to create my React app. I am new to this so I will check it out

Comment: If so the, `url-loader` should be there hopefully. Try importing the image file in your code and see if that works.

Comment: How do I format my slideData object in that case? I can't use `{}` for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should import the images instead of using relative URL:

```
import slide1Image from '/Images/sliderImages/vast_ocean.jpg
```

and then use slide1Image as the src of the image.

This is also a better approach because CRA is using webpack and may optimize the loading of the resources when you deploy the app to production.

Comment: That was my next testing to-do. I will go for it. Thanks